# Need to create a directory inside directories in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a directory inside a directory hierarchy in Perl. Below is the code I have written:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter directory name\n";
my $dir = <STDIN>;

my $newDir = "/home/test/test1/test2/$dir";
mkdir $newDir;
```

I want that the user should enter the directory name which he wants to create.

But after running this code, it is creating directory along with the `?` sign. Like if I want the directory name to be `ABC11`, it's creating a directory with the name `ABC11?`

Can someone please let me know what wrong I am doing in the code.

Thanks

Comment: ```chomp($dir)``` would help.

Comment: [Chomp function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Answer (score 4):

`$dir` contains `ABC11␊` (`ABC11` followed by a line feed), so you are creating `/home/test/test1/test2/ABC11␊`. Add [`chomp($dir);`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to remove the line feed from `$dir`.